# Problem extending Spring WebFlux application with reactive DB client: conflicting Maven dependencies?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc, dbclient

I have a small working Spring WebFlux app made basing on this code:

https://github.com/chang-chao/spring-webflux-reactive-jdbc-sample

As far as I've understood this is some kind of mix between purely reactive programming and usual blocking relational databases.

Now I have a task to add reactive DB client to my app. I stared with this guide:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-r2dbc/

But as soon as I added following dependencies to my *pom.xml*:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>r2dbc-h2</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.4.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

my WORKING app failed to start saying it couldn't find autowired repository bean. This error disappeared as soon as I've removed two dependencies above.

Initial full *pom.xml* of WORKING app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.freelance</groupId>
    <artifactId>studentlist</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>student-list</name>
    <description>Spring WebFlux application for managing students</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.10.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.200</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I suppose some dependencies are conflicting with each other. Is there a way to actually use these dependencies with all my other dependencies so I'll be able to follow that guide?

I don't know if app's Java code is needed for this question, and if it is, which pieces. For now I'll just add *application.properties*:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2_console

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/studentlist
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

logging.level.org.springframework=warn
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=trace
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=warn
logging.level.io.netty=warn

spring.datasource.maximum-pool-size=100
```

Adding **either** of these two dependencies, `spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc` or `r2dbc-h2`, without the second one is enough to cause this error:

```
2020-10-20 15:31:26.008  WARN 11580 --- [           main] onfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'studentController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'studentService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'studentService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'studentRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.freelance.studentlist.repository.StudentRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2020-10-20 15:31:26.123 ERROR 11580 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field studentRepository in com.freelance.studentlist.service.StudentServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.freelance.studentlist.repository.StudentRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.freelance.studentlist.repository.StudentRepository' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I removed JPA dependency and I'm currently trying to make things work with just r2dbc.

I suppose my application.properties would no longer be valid. Could you please help me with changing it? I use this code fragment from the guide:

```
public class R2DBCConfiguration extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public H2ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new H2ConnectionFactory(
                H2ConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                        .url("jdbc:h2:~/studentlist;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4")
                        .username("sa")
                        .build());
    }
}
```

I strongly suspect that such `url` is not valid for r2dbc. What would be valid substitution for `jdbc:h2:~/studentlist` URL in case of r2dbc H2 (not in-memory, just local DB)?

How should I change this block of code in *application.properties* ? URL in particular!

```
**spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/studentlist**
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
```

Please help if you know! Can't google an appropriate example for now...

Comment: jpa and reactive don't work together afaik. JPA is blocking and doesn't work with/uses r2dbc.

Comment: Spring Boot will configure R2DBC for you if you fill the correct properties in the `application.properties`. If your guide doesn't use R2DBC check the Spring Boot reference guide for the correct properties to set.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your feedback!

I've edited my question. 

I've found this in Spring Boot reference guide, but for postgresql and with different formatting:

`spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:postgresql://localhost/test
spring.r2dbc.username=dbuser
spring.r2dbc.password=dbpass`



I came up with this:




 `spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:h2:~/studentlist
spring.r2dbc.username=sa
spring.r2dbc.password=`

Comment: @M.Deinum Would it be correct substitution (considering my setup) for this:




`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/studentlist
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver`

I'd be grateful for your validation! :)

Comment: @M.Deinum Sorry for bad formatting, I'm new.

Is it correct to substitute `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/studentlist` with `spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:h2:~/studentlist`? This is the main point I'd like to clarify...

Comment: Don't add information as comments that is unreadable, that being said you are now also asking a different question than your initial one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `spring.datasource` is for the traditional Jdbc data source, to configure an R2dbc connection, use `spring.r2dbc` prefix instead in Spring Boot [application.properties](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/boot/src/main/resources/application.properties).

Check [my Spring R2dbc example](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample), if you are new to Spring Data R2dbc, the docs in Readme.md.